# How to avoid finally or avoid forward in Servlet switch case?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

This is the code in doPost:

```
try {
    switch (request.getParameter("action")){
        case "delete":
            request.setAttribute("message", "Deleting...");
            break;
        case "update":
            request.setAttribute("message", "Updating...");
            break;
        case "new":
            response.sendRedirect("createNew.jsp");     
            break;
        default:
            super.doPost(request, response);
            break;
    }
} finally {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("backHome.jsp").forward(request, response);
    out.close();
}
```

The problem is in the finally I'm getting this exception when the case is 'new':
java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Answer (score 1):

In case of "new" you are doing `response.sendRedirect("createNew.jsp");`. At this point response stream is written.

In finally you are doing `request.getRequestDispatcher("backHome.jsp").forward(request, response);`. It is forwarding to another url.

But since on response already some content is written another forward cannot happen. This throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

Comment: and, what can I do to solve this? can you help?

Comment: Do you want to execute what is in finally for all cases?

Comment: finally redirects, but if any other case redirects to another way don't generate exception.

Comment: Extract out what you have in finally into a separate method. Call the method from ease switch case where you need it. You do not need in case "new" as its already redirecting and then you cannot forward to another page.